# How to redirect to admin all posts page (domain/wp-admin/edit.php) after publishing, submitting or save draft

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, post, publish

I am trying to redirect to admin all posts page (domain/wp-admin/edit.php) after publish, submitting for review or saving draft

I have tried the below code and it is working perfectly but the problem now is that I can no longer preview the post while editing. If I click on preview it redirect to the all post page as well. Please someone help.

```
//redirection after create
add_action('save_post','redirect_page');
    function redirect_page(){
    $type=  get_post_type();
    switch ($type){
    case "post":
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?msg=post';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    break;
    case "product":
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=product&msg=page';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    break;
    case "page":
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=page&msg=page';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I have a feeling that preview causes an autosave, so I wonder if you can check for that. Perhaps with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_post_autosave/